# How to use menu in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-menu

I am looking for menu in layout.. how to do it.. i don't want default Menu in action bar. because i made it Disable.. its no use in my application.. I am not good in this.. plz say me some sample to do this.. thank u in advance.

I am using ice cream sandwich.sdk 11

Below images showing using action bar its showing menu in this way... i dnt want in this way because i am not using Action bar in my App
[image]

Here is my actual app which contains linear layout and i need a menu in this layout. please help me..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a series of custom views and handle their `onClick' methods to implement the switching of fragments to act as a menu?

See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831124/action-bar-in-api-level-3-0-but-still-support-api-3-0) of how I implemented a custom ActionBar. Even though its an action bar the principle is the same.